# JSON function is failed to load the webmethod static event in Asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

When I am calling JSON to load the webmethod static event at that time that event is not loading [I seen by doing debug mode] by clicking the submit button in Asp.net C#. In the place of the whole form i.e. whole webpage is loading. But I don't want to load the whole webpage.

Here is my code

This is the client side code

```
<input type="submit" id="btn_save" value="Save" class="button" />

$(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btn_save", function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "schoolregistration.aspx/EntrySave",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ name: $('#txt_schoolname').val() }),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d) {
                            alert("Successfully Added School Registration...!!!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("Error! Try again...");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is the server side code

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void EntrySave(string schoolName)
    {
         //here is the code
    }
```

Comment: try using e.preventdefault()

Comment: have you kept a break point at EntrySave(string schoolName) ? it hit ? also change input type to button from submit

Comment: I have kept break point in entrysave method but in that load is not coming even I change submit to button @krishna

Comment: means break point doesn't hit ?

Comment: Yah....that only I mean

Comment: Krishna is there any other solution.....????

Comment: @Bhaktuu ....i tried but nothing work.... :(

Comment: The data you send to the method contains name as a parameter, not schoolName, what does the server return as a response after you submit the request (debugging tools, network tab). Also, where is your prevent default, if you added it, please update the question with your latest code